# How can I get userinfo from the bearer token of RedHat Openshift?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openshift, redhat

I have configured the OAuth client on RedHat OpenShift so that I can do SSO for my application using the inbuilt OAuth server of the  RedHat OpenShift cluster. I got redirected to OCP login page, authenticated via OCP, and got the access_token as well. But now I want to get userinfo from the token I got. But it seems API /oauth/userinfo is not returning the user information.
Getting this error when I try GET /oauth/userinfo

[REST API /oauth/userinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlYv6.png)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The `/oauth/userinfo` is apparently not there. You can get the user information using OpenShift API itself [/apis/user.openshift.io/v1/users/{name}](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/rest_api/user_and_group_apis/user-user-openshift-io-v1.html)

The thing that I was missing is that a current logged in user is returned when you put **~** (tilde) to the path, so **`GET /apis/user.openshift.io/v1/users/~`**

```js
{
  kind: "User",
  apiVersion: "user.openshift.io/v1",
  metadata: {
    name: "kube:admin",
    selfLink: "/apis/user.openshift.io/v1/users/kube%3Aadmin",
    creationTimestamp: null,
  },
  identities: null,
  groups: [
    "system:authenticated",
    "system:cluster-admins",
  ],
}
```

As I'm using CodeReady containers for the development, I have URLs set up like this (Node.js/Next.js/next-auth):

```js
export const OpenShiftOAuthProvider = {
  id: "openshift",
  name: "OpenShift",
  type: "oauth",
  version: "2.0",
  params: { grant_type: "authorization_code" },
  scope: "user:full",
  idToken: false,
  accessTokenUrl: "https://oauth-openshift.apps-crc.testing/oauth/token",
  profileUrl: "https://api.crc.testing:6443/apis/user.openshift.io/v1/users/~",
  authorizationUrl:
    "https://oauth-openshift.apps-crc.testing/oauth/authorize?response_type=code",
  clientId: "<yourclientid>",
  clientSecret: "<yourclientsecret>"
  async profile(profile) {
    return {
      id: profile.metadata.name,
      name: profile.metadata.name
    };
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks, @Vojtěch Sázel I was also able to figure it out. Any idea how to get roles data of the user?

Comment: I would say that it could be this one, but not sure:
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/rest_api/role_apis/rolebinding-authorization-openshift-io-v1.html